# matlab area under Gaussian curve 'trapz(y)' and 'trapz(x,y)' function which is more accurate?

Tags: matlab

I am very new to mat lab and I am trying to get to grips with integrating under a curve.

I wanted to see this difference between using the 'trapz(y)' and 'trapz(x,y)' to find the area under a curve of a Gaussian function what I can not seem to understand is why I am getting two different area values and I am trying to figure which one is more accurate.

```
dataset = xlsread('Lab 3 Results 11.10.18 (1).xlsx','Sheet3','C6:D515');
x=dataset(:,1);
a1=38.38;
b1=1179;
c1=36.85;
d1=6.3
y=a1*exp(-((x-b1)/c1).^2)-d1;
int1=trapz(x,y)
int2=trapz(y)
```

So when I run this code I get int1=1738.3 and int2=5.78.4 but when I integrated this function by hand using the trapezium rule my ans came out to be nearer int1 rather that int2 is there anyone that could shed some light on this if possible? I just cant imagen visulay how matlab is using the trapz rule two different ways,

Comment: Why would `int2` (integration _without_ taking into the specific position of `x` points into account) give you an accurate result? Unless your data are regularly placed (with the same `dx=1` all around) the positions matter, so `trapz(x,y)` is the only sane approach. Why would you even consider the other?

Comment: @SardarUsama I have edited through, but thought I did post up the data with my code as I pasted it in maybe I did not. I apologise for this

Comment: @AndrasDeak  I did not know about the trap(y) unit spacing but after reading more on the documentaion I have a better understanding the trapz was given to me by a friend of mine but he didn't explain what it did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither implementation is more accurate, but `trapz(y)` assumes unit spacing of each data point (e.g., spacing between data points is uniformly x = 1). See [trapz documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/trapz.html).

Since you know the x-coordinates, use `trapz(x,y)`.